# how to find Master-key and Session-ID on windows for decryption of SSl/TLS traffic using wireshark?

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark

I have a C++ application that has a SSL/TLS communication with its own server and i don't have any access to that server. I'm trying to find out what is it sending from my PC to the server.

I tried burp and fiddler as man-in-middle but it didn't work. The application does not support Proxy so i tried routing the traffic using proxifier to burp and fiddler but it didn't work.

So I  came up with these articles https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Psst+Your+Browser+Knows+All+Your+Secrets+/16415 and http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4229/follow-ssl-stream-using-master-key-and-session-id

I just need to know , How I can find Master-key and Session-ID to decrypt SSL/TLS trafic.

Comment: What library or framework are you using for SSL/TLS? The *easiest* way would be to use `eNULL` and/or `aNULL` as ciphers *if* the server allows it. With `eNULL`, everything is in the clear. With `aNULL`, Fiddler and Burp will work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the TLS cipher suite being used. If the ciphersuite uses forward secrecy (DHE) you *cannot* decrypt the stream. If it uses RSA encryption then you need at least the private key of the server. If it also uses client authentication then you would also need the private key of the client. if it uses symmetric encryption you need the symmetric (master) key from either one of them.

But if you **do** have a C++ application, I would simply add logging to that application (at the lowest level).

Comment: I actually I found a good program to dump the memory and get the Master key which i was not successful yet but when i do I will give the answer here. But what you said is a good idea . How I can add logging to that application at the lowest level ? Will you please explain it more to me ?

Comment: You take a logging framework, add it to your C-application and log the stream before it hits the SSL socket? This will of course require programming and recompilation (this *is* SO).

Comment: Wireshark can decrypt plain-RSA using the server privatekey **or ANY keychange** (since 2011) using the master or premaster secret if it can be obtained from either endpoint -- which SSL/TLS endpoints are usually designed to prevent, but there are sometimes debugging-type features to get them. This is explained in detail at the link in the question. You do not ever need a client privatekey, since that is used *only* for auth and does not contribute anything to the session keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following alrternates on a x86 windows

STRACE - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emmanubo/archive/2007/06/04/introduction-to-strace-httpreplay-support-tools.aspx

SOCKTRC if this app is on windows checkout 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emmanubo/archive/2007/08/03/socktrc-tool.aspx

HTTPREPLAY - 
generally used for browsers but here can be used to view the responses in the UI

Comment: these tools are excellent but for non encrypted connections such as http but not for https

Comment: These tools hook before encryption happens and captures post decryption but yes this not to capture keys but decrypted traffic